# Highchart Basic Column in Yii2

Tags: php, highcharts, yii2

I want to create a graph using highcharts with Yii2, the data is employee leave of employment that wants to be displayed by month each year.

Here I use postgresql, and I create a query like this :

```
workleavedb=# SELECT to_char(start_date,'Mon') AS mon,employee.name,count(workleave.id) AS total FROM workleave INNER JOIN employee ON
 workleave.employee_id = employee.id WHERE start_date >= '2018-01-01' AND start_date <= '2018-12-31'  GROUP BY 1,2;
```

result :

```
 mon |           name           | total
-----+--------------------------+-------
 Aug | ALEX NOERDIN             |     1
 Jul | ALEX NOERDIN             |     1
 Jul | ANNA MARRIAM             |     2
```

how to display data whose value is empty on postgresql, and by month.
I want the query results like this :

```
  mon |           name           | total
-----+--------------------------+-------
 Jan | ALEX NOERDIN             |     0
 Jan | ANNA MARRIAM             |     0
 Feb | ALEX NOERDIN             |     0
 Feb | ANNA MARRIAM             |     1
 Mar | ALEX NOERDIN             |     1
 Mar | ANNA MARRIAM             |     0
 Apr | ALEX NOERDIN             |     1
 Apr | ANNA MARRIAM             |     0
 Mei | ALEX NOERDIN             |     1
 Mei | ANNA MARRIAM             |     2 
 Jun | ALEX NOERDIN             |     2
 Jun | ANNA MARRIAM             |     1
 Jul | ALEX NOERDIN             |     0
 Jul | ANNA MARRIAM             |     0
 Aug | ALEX NOERDIN             |     0
 Aug | ANNA MARRIAM             |     0
 Sep | ALEX NOERDIN             |     0
 Sep | ANNA MARRIAM             |     0
 Okt | ALEX NOERDIN             |     0
 Okt | ANNA MARRIAM             |     0
 Nov | ALEX NOERDIN             |     0
 Nov | ANNA MARRIAM             |     0
 Dec | ALEX NOERDIN             |     0
 Dec | ANNA MARRIAM             |     0
```

And I'm trying to create chart using Yii2 and highchart widget 
First, I create a function to retrieve data from the database query results in the Model

Model :

```
public static function getGraph(){
    $sql = "select to_char(start_date,'Mon') as bln,pegawai.nama,count(cuti.id) as total from cuti inner join pegawai on cuti.pegawai_id = pegawai.id group by 1,2";
    $result = Yii::$app->db->createCommand($sql)->queryAll();
    return $result;
}
```

Controller :

```
public function actionGraphic()
{
   $data = Report::getGraph();
   return $this->render('graphic', [
   'dgrafik' => $data
   ]);
}
```

View :

```
  use dosamigos\highcharts\HighCharts;

   //use miloschuman\highcharts\Highcharts;
   /* @var $this yii\web\View */

   foreach($dgrafik as $values){
      $a[0]= ($values['nama']);
      $c[]= ($values['bln']);
      $b[]= array('type'=> 'column', 'name' =>$values['nama'], 'data' => array((int)$values['total']));
   }

   echo
   Highcharts::widget([
      'clientOptions' => [
         'chart'=>[
            'type'=>'column'
         ],
         'title' => ['text' => 'Graphic Leave Work'],
         'xAxis' => [
            'categories' => $c
         ],
         'yAxis' => [
            'title' => ['text' => 'Total']
         ],
         'series' => $b
      ]
   ]);
```

But the graphical display does not match what I want. The graph of the result of the query looks like this:
[image: Result] 
I want to create a graph like this
[image: My Expectations Chart]

Comment: You have used `highcharts` tag, but the problem doesn't seem to be about a chart - rather about data. If you'll have problems with Highcharts then please provide a demo with hard-coded, exemplary data.

Comment: how to make array in php to display chart like above

Comment: Hi Melati Kusumawati, here is an example how the series structure should looks like for this type of chart: http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/8umkew53/

Comment: yes really like that, I've tried if enter data manually. but I want the data series to be obtained from the array taken from the database

Comment: Horay, I found a way out to show multiple series. thanks